# How can you disable "Would you like to temporarily mute this conversation?" prompts for notifications on the iOS lock screen?

Tags: ios, notifications, settings, lockscreen

Since maybe iOS 15 through iOS 16, sometimes these prompts randomly appear in notification cards for apps on the iOS lock screen:

[image: Would you like to temporarily mute this conversation prompt]

I always want to receive all notifications and never want to mute any conversations, but since this comes up randomly, sometimes I might accidentally tap "Mute...".

How can I make it so that these prompts never appear?

Comment: how often have you tried hitting Not Now? I rarely see these anymore, likely because I never choose Mute...but perhaps it's my imagination

Comment: I have seen these suggestions every day for several years, I wish they would stop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try to make these prompts show up less often.

First, you could start engaging more with notifications from the apps you're being prompted to mute. One of the reasons you might be getting the option to mute notifications is that you aren't responding to those notifications in the first place. If you open some of the notifications from the app in question, you should see less of the "temporarily mute notifications" prompt.

Second, and counterintuitively, you could try clicking the "mute" button to turn off notifications, and then manually turning notifications for that app back on from your settings. From anecdotal experience, if you select the "not now" option, it seems the prompt will simply continue showing up later. Instead, try going along with the prompts but then reversing your notifications back to your desired settings immediately afterwards.

Third, make sure none of your notifications are set to the "deliver quietly" option. Some people have suggested that the mute notifications prompt comes up more often when your apps are set to deliver notifications quietly. If your Slack notifications are set to deliver quietly, for instance, try turning off that feature to see if it reduces the unwanted prompts.

Source: https://www.iphonetricks.org/stop-temporarily-mute-notifications-on-iphone/